# Add an article preview to the gnus-summary-line-format

Tags: buffers, gnus, email, previewing

I am using gnus to read my email and the current setting for the gnus-summary-line-format in my .gnus.el is

```
(gnus-summary-line-format 
  "%U%~(pad-left 5)R: %~(max-right 25)D | %~(pad-right 25)~(max-right 25)a | %~(max-right 50)s \n")
```

Is there a way to modify this setting in order to show a short preview of each article in the summary buffer (say the first line, or the first x characters of the corresponding email) ?

This question is raised in [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail#toc17) but I could not find answer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: That would be interesting indeed. But I think you can't do that in a good way because Gnus usually loads the article not before you select it. So any hack for making you suggestion work will need to load all articles in the summary which is probably very slow.